# RegEx in C# Replace Method

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write the RegEx for replacing "name" part in below string.

```
 \profile\name\details
```

Where name: -Can have special characters
            -No spaces

Let's say I want to replace "name" in above path with ABCD, the result would be

```
 \profile\ABCD\details
```

What would be the RegEx to be used in Replace for this?
I have tried `[a-zA-Z0-9@#$%&*+\-_(),+':;?.,!\[\]\s\\/]+$` but it's not working.

Comment: Show us the regex you have created.

Comment: name is dynamic, it's just an example.

Comment: @CinCout updated my answer with the example which I used.

Comment: name is dynamic, but the other part of string are constants? \profile\ and \details

Comment: @EICOnrado Yes, you are correct, name is dynamic but other parts like "\" and profile and details are constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your dynamic part is surrounded by two static part you can use them to find it.

```
\\profile\\(.*)\\details
```

Now if you want to replace only the middle part you can either use [LookAround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
string pattern = @"(?<=\\profile\\).*(?=\\details)";
string substitution = @"titi";
string input = @"\profile\name\details
\profile\name\details
";
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
```

Or use the [replacement patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions) `$`*GroupIndex*

```
string pattern = @"(\\profile\\)(.*)(\\details)";
string substitution = @"$1Replacement$3";
string input = @"\profile\name\details
\profile\name\details
";
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
```

For readable [nammed group  substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions#substituting-a-named-group) is a possibility.

Comment: I didn't address the special characters set you had in your original question but you can simply use it in those regex. I will recommend using the second may it a little bit more readable when regex is complex. If you need extra information about $ substitution I recommend [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions)

Comment: Recommending MSDN:)

Comment: I find MSDN just fine. Alll msdn link go dead every 4-5 years when they rebuild the documentation. And the github of the documentation is quite active making many anchor go dead. (fixed one in this answer). But it's a good source of information. If I had to pick one static source of information it will the the MSDN and referencesource.microsoft.com other StackOverflow.

Comment: Microsoft TechNet, then MSDN. But now it's Microsoft Doc (learn.microsoft.com). I stop following the rebranding in 2015